# How can I select links that lead to urls ending with "/foo-bar"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to style some tags on SE with custom colors based on their tag, using CSS only.

This shouldn't be too hard, for:

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/foo-bar" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">foo-bar</a>
```

...should be easily matchable with a selector such as:

```
a.post-tag[href$=/foo-bar]
```

...where the slash would be required to match [foo-bar](/questions/tagged/foo-bar) but not [baz-foo-bar](/questions/tagged/baz-foo-bar).

However, it isn't that simple. Both the dash and the slash seem to prevent the selector from working. Luckily I can work around that by [escaping](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cssescapenotation) characters, so `/` becomes `\5c` and `-` becomes `\2d`.

This doesn't seem to match anything either, however:

```
a.post-tag[href$=\5cfoo\2dbar]
```

...whereas `a.post-tag[href$=foo\2dbar]` *does* have some matches, but again too many of them.

**How can I select an href ending in "/foo-bar" using CSS?**

Comment: I'm using Chromium 12.0.703.0 today.

Comment: `\5cfoo\2dbar` probably doesn't work because the escapes are seen as `\5cf` and `\2db`. From the same article: "If a character following the escape sequence is also a valid hexadecimal digit, you must either include six digits in the escape, or use a whitespace character to terminate the escape." I couldn't get `\00005cfoo\00002dbar` to work either though... but quotes are much easier to read anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply encase the value in the attribute selector in quotes so you don't need to escape anything, just like how you quote attribute values in HTML:

```
a.post-tag[href$="/foo-bar"]
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/eBf6H)